# Reach-Routers navigate() with an offset for anchor links?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, anchor-scroll, reach-router

Is there a way to do

```
navigate('/#about')
```

with `reach-router`, but with an offset of, say, `-16px`?
I haven't been able to find anything on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a state to the link like so:

```
...

navigate(
    "/#about/",
    {
        state: { offset: "-16px" },
    }
)

...
```

and then access the state from the destination component. You can pass it to any part of that component.

Read more about this here: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/#add-state-to-programmatic-navigation

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to listen to route changes and call `scroll(0, -16);` if the url contains the anchor. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll. Maybe calling `scroll` after calling `navigate` is enough.